# Libgdx sceene2d and Input Processor not updating screen

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am rather new to the libgdx Framework so I hope I am not asking anything stupid, but I have a problem with updating my screen on the toucheEvent. It seems that the touch event fires, but the stage is not updated so the screen is all the time the same. Here is the code

MainClass

```
public class MainGame implements Screen {
public LabirintGame game;
public Stage stage;
public OrthographicCamera camera;
public ActorM rigth;
public ActorM wrong;

public MainGame(LabirintGame game) {
    this.game = game;
    this.camera = new OrthographicCamera();

}


@Override
public void show() {
    this.camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
    stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
    stage.clear();
    Words group = new Words(stage);
    InputMultiplexer inputMultiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();

    inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stage);
    inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(new MyInputProcessor(stage, camera));
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer);
    //Add wrong and rigth boxes
    rigth = new ActorM("box", 0, 0, 200,200);
    wrong = new ActorM("box",(game.width - 230), 0, 200, 200);
    wrong.moveBy(200,200);

    Button createButtons = new Button();
    createButtons.setStyle("atlas-besede/besede.atlas", "buttonOff", "buttonOn");
    TextButton ValidationButton = createButtons.createButton("Validate", (game.width/2), 0, 150, 150);
    ValidationButton.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            game.setScreen(new Labirint(game));
            return true;
        }

    });


    stage.addActor(ValidationButton);
    stage.addActor(rigth);
    stage.addActor(wrong);


    List<String> backgrounds = Arrays.asList("s", "z");
    for (int i = 0; i < backgrounds.size(); i++) {
        Word  actor = new Word(backgrounds.get(i),(i + 1) * 300, 300, 100, 100);
        actor.setPosition((i + 1) * 300, 300);
        actor.setName(backgrounds.get(i));
        group.addActor(actor);
    }
    stage.addActor(group);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

    stage.draw();
    game.batch.begin();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    game.batch.end();

}
```

ActorM

```
package com.mygdx.game;

public class ActorM extends Actor {
public SpriteBatch batch;
public TextureAtlas atlas;
public TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion region;
Sprite sprite;
public int x;
public int y;
public int width;
public int height;

public ActorM(String actorName, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    //this.region = region;
    super();
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("atlas-start/atlas-start.atlas"));
    sprite = atlas.createSprite(actorName);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.setBounds(0, 0, sprite.getWidth(), sprite.getHeight());
    setTouchable(Touchable.disabled);
    setName(actorName);
    setPosition(x,y);
}

@Override
public void draw (Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    batch.draw(sprite, x,y, width, height);
}
public void move(int posX){
    this.x = this.x +  posX;
}
```

}

MyInputProcessor

```
public class MyInputProcessor implements InputProcessor {
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private Stage stage;
private Vector2 coordinates;
private Music sound;
public MyInputProcessor( Stage stage, OrthographicCamera camera) {
    this.stage = stage;
    this.camera = camera;
}

@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button)        

    {
        //Gdx.app.log("", "x " + screenX + " y " + screen`enter code here`Y + " pointer " + pointer);
        Vector2 coordinates = stage.screenToStageCoordinates(new Vector2((float)screenX,(float)screenY));
        Actor  hitactor = stage.hit(coordinates.x, coordinates.y, true);
        Gdx.app.log("", coordinates.toString());
        if (hitactor != null){
            //Gdx.app.log("", "HIT" + hitactor.getName());
            Gdx.app.log("", "HIT" + hitactor.getRotation());
            hitactor.setRotation(hitactor.getRotation() + 1f);
            hitactor.setPosition(5,5);
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        coordinates = stage.screenToStageCoordinates(new Vector2((float)screenX,(float)screenY));
        Actor hitactor = stage.hit(coordinates.x, coordinates.y, true);

        if (hitactor != null){
            Gdx.app.log("", "Drag");
            hitactor.setRotation(hitactor.getRotation() + 1f);
        }
        camera.update();
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see where you set the Stage dimensions. You are creating a camera but where do you assign it to stage?

Answer (score 0):

Your "`ValidationButton`" uses an InputProcessor that always returns true and it's the first actor in the stage, so nothing else in the stage will ever get an opportunity to respond to touch down events. Furthermore, since your stage is the first input processor in your InputMultiplexer, your other input processor never gets an opportunity to respond to touch down events either.

You should use an EventListener on your button instead of an InputListener, so much of the logic will be taken care of for you.

By the way, your ActorM class is spawning a SpriteBatch that it never uses. SpriteBatch takes up significant memory, and there's no need for there to be more than one of them in your game. The Stage already has a reference to a SpriteBatch that it passes into your Actor's draw method, so the Actor does not need to create or even reference a SpriteBatch.

Also, your ActorM class is loading a complete copy of a TextureAtlas for itself so there will be duplicate Textures loaded for each instance of ActorM, and you lose all the benefits of a TextureAtlas, since you won't be using it for sprite batching. You need to load the TextureAtlas only one time, and pass a reference of it into the constructor of your ActorM class, so they can all share the same Texture.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the tips, but the problem was not the ValidationButton because I can access the events. The problem is that when I went to update the screen position of the object is changed but the screen is not updated.